# Aligning of the form - css, html

Tags: html, css, forms

Heya I'm really basic with this CSS and web design. I would like billing info table and the form to be left aligned, I have tried everything and this is a last resort. The form and title billing is on the right hand side of the page.

This is a framework and there is a header, footer, navigation and side bare includes with the middle include being the main page.

Here is the code for the middle include.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Billing Info</title>
<script language="javascript">
function validate(){
    var f=document.form1;
    if(f.name.value==''){
        alert('Your name is required');
        f.name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    f.command.value='update';
    f.submit();
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validate()">
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="billing" />
<div align="left">
<div style="padding-top:50px">

    <h1 align="left">Billing Info</h1>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="2px" align="left">
        <tr><td>Order Total:&nbsp;&pound;</td><td><?=get_total_with_shipping()?>    </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Your Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="address" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Phone:</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Place Order" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I can't post a picture due to my rating but any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: `align` attribute is deprecated. Use a separate css stylesheet and load it into you html then try with `float` or `display: inline-block`

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. The form and table appear on the left-hand side of the page, not the right: http://jsfiddle.net/DUUuJ/

Comment: we are not clear what exactly do you need because i have checked it your code your form is coming in left side included heading billing also check the fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/AmHke/

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your problem like the rest, but I'll give it a shot:

Have a look at the whole source code of your page. If this is the "middle" part, then you're probably using multiple    elements.

Then place the  and 's inside the , not the other way around.
Also, don't use inline styling (like this: )
Instead, give it a class, or an ID and put the styling in the CSS section.